# Follow user in rails5 - Error UNIQUE constraint failed: relationships.follower_id, relationships.followed_id

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

> I want after the user press follow, that follow button will become unfollow.

model user:

```
 def followed(other_user)
    following << other_user
  end

  def unfollow(other_user)
    following.delete(other_user)
  end

  def following?(other_user)
    following.include?(other_user)
  end
has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
```

model Relationship:

```
 belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
 validates :follower_id, :followed_id, presence: true
```

View users:

_follow.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, @user.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %
```

_unfollow.html

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id),
             html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

shared:

_follow_form.html.erb

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <div id="follow_form">
  <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'follow' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

_stats.html.erb

```
<% @user ||= current_user %>
<div class="stats">
  <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>">
    <strong id="following" class="stat">
      <%= @user.following.count %>
    </strong>
    following
  </a>
  <a href="<%= followers_user_path(@user) %>">
    <strong id="followers" class="stat">
      <%= @user.followers.count %>
    </strong>
    followers
  </a>
</div
```

relationship_controller.tb

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.followed(user)
    redirect_to user
  end

  def destroy
    user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(user)
  end
end
```

db/schema.rb

```
create_table "relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "follower_id"
    t.integer "followed_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_followed_id"
    t.index ["follower_id", "followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id_and_followed_id", unique: true
    t.index ["follower_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id"
  end
```

after I clicked the tracking button, the number of followers will increase by 1 but when I press it again, the following error is displayed:

> ---> Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: relationships.follower_id, relationships.followed_id

Comment: How does your controller action look? Do you redirect back and the button is still "follow" instead of "unfollow"?

Comment: I have added it above so please check it out for me

Comment: Looking a the documentation for `form_for` it looks like the method should be specified directly in the options hash (rather than nesting it under the html key).
Try changing that and make sure you end up in the `destroy`action. byebug/binding.pry etc is your friend :)

Comment: params[:id] and params[:follower_id] caught me as potentially a place where you're screwing up.  Would be helpful if you posted your schema too.

Comment: I have added the Schema.rb above  !